# External DRL file loading into multiple KieBase instances

Tags: java, xml, drools

**Note: This is all using the current 6.4.0.Final implementation of the Kie library.**

Hey there. I'm trying to use Drools in a way I'm not finding much info on online (or I'm just searching the wrong things, but I've tried for a few days now), so I'd like to ask a question about my use case here.

I want to create multiple KieBase instances, as I assume that's the 'level' I should be handling this on, that each have their own secluded set of pre-generated rules upon building, somewhere **not in the resources folder** (at this moment, the root folder of application deployment).

So, if I have multiple instances of the same object A, B or C. They can all have different properties, and therefore, different rules per object.

I thought that creating a folder, in this case `./rules` with subfolders for each event would be a neat approach here. Whenever an object gets created, a relative folder gets created in this `./rules` folder.

- `./rules/A/` for object A.
- `./rules/B/` for object B.
- `./rules/C/` for object C.

Then through other means, I generate DRL files in these subfolders, essentially – correct me if I'm wrong – creating packages.

Now, when I start adding in the subobjects for object A, I'd like to apply *only* the rules inside the `./rules/A` folder to them.

So I've written the following loading class, following online examples, I'd like to load a KieBase instance specifically loading the rule files I've added to a certain objects folder:

```java
private KieBase loadKieBase(String identifier) {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();

    List<String> drlFiles = fileHandler.loadFiles(identifier);

    for (String drl : drlFiles) {
        String path = "src/main/resources/drools/" + drl;
        Resource resource = ResourceFactory.newFileResource(drl);
        kieFileSystem.write(path, resource);
    }

    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kieFileSystem);
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();

    if (results.hasMessages(Message.Level.ERROR)) {
        ...
    }

    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieBuilder.getKieModule().getReleaseId());
    KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConfiguration = kieServices.newKieBaseConfiguration();
    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.newKieBase(kieBaseConfiguration);
    return kieBase;
}
```

Logging reveals to me that the resources are being loaded correctly, which means the `kieFileSystem.write(...)` line gets a valid Resource argument. Printing the file loaded also gives me the files I want to see for the object I asked the files for. So that part's all working. However, I get the following warning:

`WARN  o.d.c.k.b.impl.AbstractKieModule - No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase`

It seems indeed no files are being written to the `src/main/resources/drools/` folder that I've made in my resources. I don't even deem this necessary – shouldn't they be loaded simply into memory anyways? Why the need to write them again, when I can load them from their pregenerated file locations?

Could this perhaps be my `kmodule.xml` file being incorrect (rather – should I even have one, if I want to basically use KieBases in memory? In my mind, it doesn't make sense to have this 'physical' reference to a knowledge package you create on the fly...)? This is the file for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule 
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <kbase name="KnowledgeBase" packages="drools">
        <ksession name="KnowledgeSession"></ksession>
    </kbase>
</kmodule>
```

Might this be correct, I run into another problem next, which might be related.

My generated DRL files use the following template for the 'headers' of the file:

```
package drools

import org.droolstest.TestTicket

global org.slf4j.Logger logger

rule "same-ticket"
    ...
end
```

After which I try to use the following calls:

```java
KieBase kieBase = loadKieBase(eventToken);
KieSession kieSession = kieBase.newKieSession();
kieSession.setGlobal("logger", logger);
```

Which crashes the application giving me this exception:

```
INFO  o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
INFO  c.p.a.c.m.r.RuleGroupClusterModule - KieBase: org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl@738b876e
INFO  c.p.a.c.m.r.RuleGroupClusterModule - KieSession: KieSession[0]
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected global [logger]
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.setGlobal(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1162)
```

This also puzzles me. I assume the KieBase has not loaded the file correctly, or something like that (which is why I included the huge build-up to this problem – I'm sorry, it's just that I have no clue where the source of my problem lies).

I find it really hard to wrap my head around what my problem might be here – apart from the `kmodule.xml` file, everything seems fine, right? So any form of help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: A sudden glance at the Similar Questions notified me of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436739/no-drl-files-found-for-the-kiebase-using-kmodule-xml). It seems really similar, but I don't think I want to generate the files in the resources folder, which is what the self-answer seems to revolve all around.

Comment: Your best plan might be the inclusion of *all* DRL files in the load-and-compile code  in your method `loadKieBase`. The error you are getting suggests that the DRL where global logger is declared is not included in the build of that KieBase - therefore make sure (by explicitly calling write to the KIE file system) that it is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. At the moment, I only have 1 test 'subfolder' with 1 rule file. Which I'm pretty sure gets loaded and which is used in a call to the kieFileSystem.write() method. Could I miss compiling components, or something alike? It doesn't seem to log any mistakes anywhere, even though I've got all that set up. You also seem to be the author of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24570355/5347955), which seems to be the approach I've also tried, so really, why could this loading go wrong, other than DRL file compilation issues?

Comment: The approach I've outlined in "this answer" works and it'll tell you whether there are any errors in the DRL.  There is, of course, always the possibility that you've made another error. - To learn whether DRLs from this or that file are correctly loaded, use just one rule per DRL file: `rule "in DRL x.drl" when then System.out.println(...); end`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that indeed there is some conflict between your way to configure kiebase (programmatically) with the kmodule.xml. Have you tried to compile and run without the kmodule.xml?The most reasonable explanation to me is that the kiebase in xml has priority over the others. I also think that this can be useful to you:

http://planet.jboss.org/post/configuration_and_convention_based_building_and_utilization